# Stop Loop when got error in switch case - Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

Tags: javascript, mysql

I want to do multiple insert statements in mysql by calling 1 query first to check then what if the result is null / no / empty then do an insert based on the existing object. I have 4 different tables that relate to the user_session table. i want to insert 1 by 1 based on the object received.

**but i dont know how to stop loop when i got an error from query.**

in this case I have an object like this:

```
{"ua":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36",
"browser":{"name":"Chrome","version":"71.0.3578.98","major":"71"},
"engine":{"name":"WebKit","version":"537.36"},
"os":{"name":"Windows","version":"10"},
"device":{},
"cpu":{"architecture":"amd64"}}
```

**But i got problem when i try to insert like this :**

> Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent
>   to the client

```
export const cookieTrack = (req, res) => {
     let queryInsertSession = `INSERT INTO user_session (id,ip_address) values ('${req.sessionID}','${ip_address}')`;
            let queryInsertSessionBrowserAndEngineOs = (table)=>{
                return `INSERTs INTO ${table} set session_id = (SELECT us.id from user_session as us where id = '${req.sessionID}' and us.ip_address = '${ip_address}'), ?   `;
            } 
            let queryInsertDevice = `INSERT INTO session_device set session_id = (SELECT us.id from user_session as us where id = '${req.sessionID}' and us.ip_address = '${ip_address}'), ?`

            db.query(queryInsertSession,(error,result)=>{
                let checkError = [];
                if(error) return res.status(400).json(error);
                if(result){
                    if (Object.keys(ua).length > 0) {

                        Object.keys(ua).forEach(key => {
                            switch (key) {
                                case 'browser':
                                    let session_browser = {};
                                    if (ua[key].hasOwnProperty('name')) {
                                        session_browser.name = ua[key].name;
                                    }
                                    if (ua[key].hasOwnProperty('version')) {
                                        session_browser.version = ua[key].version
                                    }
                                    if (Object.keys(session_browser).length > 0){
                                        db.query(queryInsertSessionBrowserAndEngineOs('session_browser'), session_browser, (error, result) => {
                                            if (error) return res.status(400).json(error);
                                        });
                                    }

                                    return;
                                case 'engine':
                                    let session_engine = {};
                                    if (ua[key].hasOwnProperty('name')) {
                                        session_engine.name = ua[key].name;
                                    }
                                    if (ua[key].hasOwnProperty('version')) {
                                        session_engine.version = ua[key].version
                                    }
                                    if (Object.keys(session_engine).length > 0){

                                        db.query(queryInsertSessionBrowserAndEngineOs('session_engine'), session_engine, (error, result) => {
                                            if (error) return res.status(400).json(error);
                                        });
                                    }

                                    return;
                                case 'os':
                                    let session_os = {};
                                    if (ua[key].hasOwnProperty('name')) {
                                        session_os.name = ua[key].name;
                                    }
                                    if (ua[key].hasOwnProperty('version')) {
                                        session_os.version = ua[key].version
                                    }

                                    if (Object.keys(session_os).length > 0){
                                        db.query(queryInsertSessionBrowserAndEngineOs('session_os'), session_os, (error, result) => {
                                            if (error) return res.status(400).json(error);
                                        });
                                    }

                                    return;
                                case 'device':
                                    let session_device = {};
                                    if (ua[key].hasOwnProperty('type') && typeof ua[key].type !== "undefined") {
                                            session_device.type = ua[key].type;
                                        }
                                    if (ua[key].hasOwnProperty('vendor') && typeof ua[key].type !== "undefined") {
                                            session_device.vendor = ua[key].vendor
                                        }
                                    if (ua[key].hasOwnProperty('model') && typeof ua[key].type !== "undefined") {
                                            session_device.model = ua[key].model
                                        }

                                    if (Object.keys(session_device).length > 0){
                                        db.query(queryInsertDevice, session_device, (error, result) => {
                                            if (error) return res.status(400).json(error);

                                        });
                                    }    
                                    return;


                                default:
                                    return;
                            }

                        });

                    }

                }
            })
}
```

in my opinion this happens because when I get a loop error it doesn't stop completely

Comment: The backtick in the SQL - that's executed a subshell right? Are they meant to be strings?

Answer (score 0):

The loop doesn't stop because you're using forEach.

When you do this `Object.keys(ua).forEach(key => { ... })` you iterate over your keys and call the function supplied as parameter on each 'key'.

If you have a `return` inside the function it'll apply to the function not the loop. The only solution I know is throw an exception. The alternative is to have an actual loop:

```
let anArray = Object.keys(ua)
for (let i = 0 ; i < anArray.length ; ++i )
{
  ... code with return statements
}
```

Comment: what do you mean ? throw an exception?

Comment: @FarisDewantoro you can throw exceptions and use a try/catch around the forEach to control the flow as in this example: 
try {
Object.keys(ua).forEach(key => {
                            switch (key) { default: throw "Error blabla"});
}
catch (err) {
console.log(err)
}